# What is the difference between TextView's style and android:textAppearance attributes?

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

If I define my `TextView` as:

```
 <TextView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

it is basically the same as doing:

```
 <TextView
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

I know that `style` is some kind of broader qualifier (i.e. one can't set all attributes in `android:textAppearance`) but then it raises the question: why bother? Is there any advantage of using `android:textAppearance` over `style`?

Answer (score 13):

From Styles and Themes https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#textappearance

> One limitation with styles is that you can apply only one style to a View. In a TextView, however, you can also specify a TextAppearance attribute which functions similarly to a style
>
> TextAppearance allows you to define text-specific styling while leaving a View’s style available for other uses. Note, however, that if you define any text attributes directly on the View or in a style, those values would override the TextAppearance values.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that style is an attribute for all the views even TextView and textAppearance only apply some 'style components' which are available only for texts. You can apply your own styles in both using styles.xml

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textAppearance

**textAppearance**

Default appearance of text: color, typeface, size, and style.

**style**

This applies to everything

Answer (score 5):

You can only have one style attribute per view, but using TextAppearance allows you to in essence define a style using the restricted set of text-relevant attributes. You can use both a style and a TextAppearance in one View.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine Styles with TextAppearance.
For instance, in TextAppearance you set all the text-related logic for a button.
In a Style you may reuse it and add extra attrbutes, such as padding, size etc.

For instance,

```
<style name="TextAppearanceTitle" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#f0f</item>
</style>

<style name="SomeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceTitle</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

It might be useful to someone, here is the list of supported attributes for TextView's TextAppearance:

```
<attr name="textColor" />
<attr name="textSize" />
<attr name="textStyle" />
<attr name="typeface" />
<attr name="fontFamily" />
<attr name="textColorHighlight" />
<attr name="textColorHint" />
<attr name="textColorLink" />
<attr name="textAllCaps" format="boolean" />
<attr name="shadowColor" format="color" />
<attr name="shadowDx" format="float" />
<attr name="shadowDy" format="float" />
<attr name="shadowRadius" format="float" />
<attr name="elegantTextHeight" format="boolean" />
<attr name="letterSpacing" format="float" />
<attr name="fontFeatureSettings" format="string" />
```

All the remaining stuff you set in a Style.

Comment: why autosize is not part of textappearance? it should be realted to text